# Acessibilidade Inconsistente: tipo parâmetro "Professor" é menos acessível que o método "Professor.Insert(Professor)"

Tags: c#, método

O que eu faço para arrumar esse erro? Fica vermelho embaixo dos métodos criado neste código.

E quando eu passo o mouse mostra:

> Acessibilidade Inconsistente: tipo parâmetro "Professor" é menos acessível que o método "Professor.Insert(Professor)"

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Escola.clsDados.BLL
{
    public class Professor
    {
        DAL.Professor dalProf = new DAL.Professor();

        public void Insert(Model.Professor oProf)
        {
            if (oProf.Nome == "")
            {
                throw new Exception("O campo nome é obrigatório");
            }
            dalProf.Insert(oProf);
        }

        public void Update(Model.Professor oProf)
        {
            if (oProf.Nome != "")
                dalProf.Update(oProf);
        }

        public void Delete(Model.Professor oProf)
        {
            if (oProf.Codigo > 0)
                dalProf.Delete(oProf);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente precisa fazer `Model.Professor` como `public` para usar em um método `public`.

Parece que não codifica pensando na acessibilidade, o campo existente não deveria ser `private`? Só porque funciona não quer dizer que está certo.

Você não pode acessar um tipo que não está acessível em certas situações, então se você tem um método público o que o contrato dele exige precisa ser público.